# How to exclude style from copied text in Prime NG editor

Tags: angular, editor, primeng

Copying text from Word or other source into ng prime editor also copying the style .I want to copy only the text value without style.

Copied text is : PrimeNG is a collection of rich UI components for Angular.

Below is the code which is getting generated

```
<p><strong style="color: rgb(32, 33, 36);">PrimeNG</strong><span style="color: rgb(32, 33, 36);">&nbsp;is a collection of rich UI components for Angular. </span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, you can get text value using the Event onTextChange:

> onTextChange -> event.textValue: Current value as text.

You should add an option to your editor, only to copy text value, but in this case you will copy the entire value, not only selected parts.

You can evaluate a custom solution:
[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)